# Calculating limit of sequence using only $1/n\to0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

First of all, thank you for visiting this thread, and thanks for whom will try helping.
So, the teacher explained to us how to calculate the limit of the sequence by only using one fact: $1/n$ goes to $0$.
However, I can't find the solution for this question, using only this fact.
In red, I wrote in Hebrew "Goes to zero".
In addition, there are about 4 or 5 more students who shared their way to solve this question, and tried the same way as I wrote. But I think we're missing some rule here.
[image: The Question's Picture]

Is it even possible to calculate the sequence's limit using only "$1/n$ goes to $0$"?
Again, thanks in advance. :)

Comment: No, your step is wrong. Consider $n \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}}$ as $n \to \infty$. It's pretty obvious that $n \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}} \to \infty$ (since we can rearrange it to $\sqrt{n}$). What you did is wrong since you get a $\infty \cdot 0$ situation, which is undefined.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I understand that we didn't actually study this. Again, thank you for your time. :)

Comment: Happy I could help :-)

Answer (score 1):

What's critical here is that the coefficients of the expressions on the right add up to $0$. The best way to handle the problem is to use that fact that
$$\sqrt{1+x} = 1+\frac x2 + \epsilon(x),$$
where $\epsilon(x)/x \to 0$ as $x\to 0$. This follows from the definition of the derivative of $\sqrt{1+x}$.

These problems are usually more mundane and handled — at the beginning of a calculus course — by a multiplication by the "conjugate" trick. For example, to handle
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt{n+3} - \sqrt{n-1},$$
you multiply by $\dfrac{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-1}}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n-1}}$ and use basic algebra, together with the $1/n\to 0$ fact to which you've alluded (in this case, you need $1/\sqrt n\to 0$).

Answer (score 0):

$$-(4\sqrt{n+3}-\sqrt{n-1}-5\sqrt{n+7}+2\sqrt{n-3})
\\=-(4\sqrt{n+3}-4\sqrt{n+7}+\sqrt{n-3}-\sqrt{n-1}+\sqrt{n-3}-\sqrt{n+7})
\\=4\frac{4}{\sqrt{n+3}+\sqrt{n+7}}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{n-3}+\sqrt{n-1}}+\frac{10}{\sqrt{n-3}+\sqrt{n+7}}
\\\le\frac{28}{2\sqrt{n-3}}.$$

Now if we take $n-3=\dfrac{m^2}{196}$, where $m$ goes to $\infty$ with $n$, this expression is positive and bounded above by

$$\frac1m$$ so it tends to zero.